# Что такое минус бесконечность в JS?

Tags: javascript

В **JS** существуют `Infinity` и `-Infinity`.

`Infinity` согласно **MDN**...

> Свойство MAX_VALUE имеет значение, приблизительно равное 1.79E+308. Значения, большие MAX_VALUE представляются как «бесконечность».

```js
console.log(1.79E+500); //Infinity
```

А как получить `-Infinity`? Число меньшее `MIN_VALUE`, будет представлено как нуль.

Comment: Например так `Number.MIN_VALUE * 10**1000 * -1`  :)

Comment: `-1/0` можно проще. Но вообще гуглить и изучать IEEE 754, если хочется реально разобраться в представлении чисел в компьютере

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так и получить: `-Infinity` или `-1.79E+500`

В статье про MIN_VALUE на MDN почему-то пропустили уточнение "положительное" в нескольких местах. На ноль заменяются только достаточно малые положительные числа, но отрицательным ничто не мешает быть сколько угодно малыми.

На заметку. Числовая шкала почти любых чисел с плавающей точкой почти в любом языке программирования выглядит следующим образом:

```
-Infinity -MAX_VALUE … -MIN_VALUE 0 MIN_VALUE … MAX_VALUE Infinity
```